# Thunder client : how to compare actual and expected response in scripting tab

Tags: web-api-testing, thunderclient

New to Thunder client. How to compare actual test results with expected ? How to define in Thunder client. Could you explain please?
Many thanks ,
Sri

Could not find any documentation for scripting with examples. And also , can you please share any documentation on scripting?

Answer (score 0):

Please find the documentation for scripting

https://github.com/rangav/thunder-client-support/blob/master/docs/filters.md#scripting